# understand sendmail log messages

Tags: email, sendmail

I sent an e-mail message from machine named `syslog-server` with command `mail -s "syslog test" test@example.net <<< "test"`. The mail message was not delivered to receiver and following messages were logged to `syslog-server` log file:

```
Mar 11 13:16:06 syslog-server sendmail[30925]: u2BBG6mY030925: from=root, size=223, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201603111116.u2BBG6mY030925@syslog-server>, relay=root@localhost
Mar 11 13:16:06 syslog-server sm-mta[30931]: u2BBG6tO030931: from=<root@syslog-server>, size=461, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201603111116.u2BBG6mY030925@syslog-server>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar 11 13:16:07 syslog-server sendmail[30925]: u2BBG6mY030925: to=test@example.net, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30223, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u2BBG6tO030931 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 11 13:16:07 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: STARTTLS=client, error: connect failed=-1, SSL_error=1, errno=0, retry=-1
Mar 11 13:16:07 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: STARTTLS=client: 30941:error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small:s3_clnt.c:3337:
Mar 11 13:16:07 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: ruleset=tls_server, arg1=SOFTWARE, relay=mail.example.com, reject=403 4.7.0 TLS handshake failed.
Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mail.example.org., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: u2BBG6tO030931: to=<test@example.net>, ctladdr=<root@syslog-server> (0/0), delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120461, relay=mail.example.org. [192.0.2.34], dsn=5.1.8, stat=User unknown
Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: u2BBG6tO030931: u2BBG9tO030941: DSN: User unknown
Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: u2BBG9tO030941: to=<root@syslog-server>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

As I am new to e-mail, could somebody explain me what happened here? As I understand, in third log line my e-mail message was accepted for delivery, then there were multiple (failed) attempts to send e-mail message over TLS, but then the e-mail was sent and remote MTA reported back that user(`test`) at `example.net` is unknown?

Comment: Agreed - it's all in the log.  What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log entries sets 1,2,3 are chained based on queueid.
Log entries set 4 is chained based on sendmail process id (pid).

1. Message is successfully passed to local main sendmail daemon at 127.0.0.1:25
   QID=**u2BBG6mY030925** (QUID_at_127.0.0.1=*u2BBG6tO030931*)

> Mar 11 13:16:06 syslog-server sendmail[30925]: **u2BBG6mY030925**: from=root, size=223, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201603111116.u2BBG6mY030925@syslog-server>, relay=root@localhost
>
> Mar 11 13:16:07 syslog-server sendmail[30925]: **u2BBG6mY030925**: to=test@example.net, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30223, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (*u2BBG6tO030931* Message accepted for delivery)

2. Receiving server mail.example.org states that "recipient is unknown"
   QID=**u2BBG6tO030931** (QID_of_bounce=*u2BBG9tO030941*)

> Mar 11 13:16:06 syslog-server sm-mta[30931]: **u2BBG6tO030931**: from=<root@syslog-server>, size=461, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201603111116.u2BBG6mY030925@syslog-server>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
>
> Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: **u2BBG6tO030931**: to=test@example.net, ctladdr=<root@syslog-server> (0/0), delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120461, relay=mail.example.org. [192.0.2.34], dsn=5.1.8, stat=User unknown
>
> Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: **u2BBG6tO030931**: *u2BBG9tO030941*: DSN: User unknown

3. Bounce mail (report about delivery problems) is sent to sender
   QID=**u2BBG9tO030941** about delivery of *u2BBG6tO030931*

> Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: *u2BBG6tO030931*: **u2BBG9tO030941**: DSN: User unknown
>
> Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[30941]: **u2BBG9tO030941**: to=<root@syslog-server>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent

4. There were problems with STARTLS (switching to encrypted connection)
   PID=**30941**

> Mar 11 13:16:07 syslog-server sm-mta[**30941**]: STARTTLS=client, error: connect failed=-1, SSL_error=1, errno=0, retry=-1
>
> Mar 11 13:16:07 syslog-server sm-mta[**30941**]: STARTTLS=client: 30941:error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small:s3_clnt.c:3337:
>
> Mar 11 13:16:07 syslog-server sm-mta[**30941**]: ruleset=tls_server, arg1=SOFTWARE, relay=mail.example.com, reject=403 4.7.0 TLS handshake failed.
>
> Mar 11 13:16:09 syslog-server sm-mta[**30941**]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mail.example.org., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256

---

Send as **root** a test message in verbose mode with SMTP session tracking to be 100% sure.  STARTTLS problems and bad email domain used in sender address ("naked" host name) may lead to "misleading" log entries.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -Am -v -- test@example.net <<END
Subject: test email subject

test email body
END
```